# How to assign value to const vector of pointers of objects in c++?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm currently trying to assing the value to const std::vector. Age is class derived from class Animal.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Animal{
  public:
    Animal(std::string name) : name_(name) {}
    std::string getName() {return name_;}
  protected:
    std::string name_;
};


class Age : public Animal
{
  public:
    Age(std::string name, int age) : Animal(name), age_(age) {}
  private:
    int age_;
};

class AllAnimals
{
  public:
    AllAnimals(){};
    void setVector(const std::vector<Age*> v) {all_animals_ = v;}
  private:
    const std::vector<Age*> all_animals_;
};



int main()
{
  AllAnimals animals();
  std::vector<Age*> all_animals;
  all_animals.push_back(new Age("Cat", 3));
  all_animals.push_back(new Age("Dog", 4));
  all_animals.push_back(new Age("Mouse", 2));
  all_animals.push_back(new Age("Duck", 1));
  return 0;
}
```

After compiling the code I get the error message:

```
 error: passing ‘const std::vector<Age*>’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive] void setVector(const std::vector<Age*> v) {all_animals_ = v;}
```

What is the problem with my implementation and how can I assign the value for all_animals_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assign to the vector after it has been initialized, it is `const`. The solution is to initialize it. As your code is dealing with raw-owning pointers and would require some reminders about correct usage of them or using smart-pointers instead, but that isnt the topic of the question, I allowed myself to simply the example a lot:

```
#include <vector>

struct foo {
    const std::vector<int> x;
    foo(const std::vector<int>& a) : x(a) {}
};

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4};
    foo f(v);
}
```

Members are initialized before the body of the constructor is executed, hence the place to initialize it is the constructors member initializer list.

Note that making a member `const` is rarely a good idea. For example you cannot copy instances when they have a `const` member. If you want a member not getting modified after construction this is a situation where encapsulation really pays off. Make the member private and don't provide any write-access from outside. Then from outside the member is non-modifyable, but you can still copy instances of the class.

PS: The error message can be a little confusing here. It refers to the `=` of `std::vector`, so the `this` in the message is the vector, not your `AllAnimals` instance. "passing XY as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers" is the typical error message you get when there is a problem with const-correctness on a member function.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand it a little better.